# Extend the list over a certain length

Tags: python, list

I have a list that has several elements, but I would reduce this list to a different length. How do I do that?
For example this is my list: `l1 = [1,2]`

This is my second list: `l2 = [[10,9,8],[7,6,5],[4,3,2]] #len(l2) = 3`

So `l2` has three elements. What I want that my list `l1` contains also three elements with the `l1` elements `l1_new = [[1,2], [1,2], [1,2]]`.

I looked at the length of `l2` and predicted this length to `l1` and copied the elements of `l1` as often as the length of `l2`.

Comment: What does this have to do with pandas?

Comment: `[l1.copy() for _ in l2]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can multiply a list to extend it to a certain length. So make a list containing `l1`, and multiply it by the length you want.

```
l1_new = [l1] * len(l2)
```

Note that all the elements of `l1_new` are references to the same list in `l1`. So if you change `l1[1]` or `l1_new[0][1]` it will also change `l1[1][1]`. If you need new lists, use a list comprehension.

```
l1_new = [l1[:] for _ in range(len(l2))]
```

Comment: The first solution is really bad as it introduces unwanted shared structures that will fail silently.  The second solution doesn't work at all.

Comment: I specifically mentioned the sharing problem. But you're right about the second one, I forgot to use `len()`. That's fixed.